# Apache Zeppelin Upgrade to Flink 1.4.2

Tags: apache-flink, apache-zeppelin

I tried to upgrade Apache Zeppelin to use Flink 1.4.2. Checking the source of the Flink Zeppelin interpreter I did not find anything that seems materials from a Flink version point of view so I just updated the Flink verion in the pom file to 1.4.2 and run a new build from source which surprisingly worked. Running the Flink batch example notebook (or a streaming example of myself) I get the following error which I cannot properly understand

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:274)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:258)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter$4.call(RemoteInterpreter.java:233)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter$4.call(RemoteInterpreter.java:229)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:135)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:228)
at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:437)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:183)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Would be great to get some understanding how we can move to newest Flink version in Zeppelin.

Comment: BTW, the build without the version upgrade to Flink 1.4.2 works fine. So it has something to do with the Flink upgrade, some pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

A [recent thread](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/9d281e2134fa879087c29600717f02d949f327c2079c2c4824e3a06d@%3Cuser.flink.apache.org%3E) on the Flink users mailing list covered how to update Zeppelin to use Flink 1.4.2. The email included an image that doesn't appear in the archive, so I'll include the relevant info here:

You need to set two properties in Zeppelin, which point to the jobmanager of the flink cluster to be used by the zeppelin server:

```
jobmanager.rpc.host
jobmanager.rpc.port
```

Note that there are also properties named host and port, but they aren't used for this purpose.

And you'll need to build Zeppelin using profile scala-2.11 and Flink 1.4.2.

Comment: David thanks a lot. Will try it out as soon as possible. Any plans to include the Flink UI sinks for Zeppelin from https://github.com/TU-Berlin-DIMA/i2?

Comment: Where can I find documentation on building using different version of scala and flink?